# bootstrap 3 not show tooltip on jQuery selec2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I design my selectbox using select2 plugin. now, i need to show tooltip on top of selectbox.

HTML :

```
<select class="selectD input-sm" name="newsoptions_amount" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Gallery Cover">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
    <br><br><br>

    <a class="width24 thumbcheck" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Gallery Cover" data-id="">test tooltip</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".selectD").select2({
        allowClear: true
    });
});
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();

/*     
 * Add collapse and remove events to boxes
 */
$("[data-widget='collapse']").click(function () {
    //Find the box parent        
    var box = $(this).parents(".box").first();
    //Find the body and the footer
    var bf = box.find(".box-body, .box-footer");
    if (!box.hasClass("collapsed-box")) {
        box.addClass("collapsed-box");
        bf.slideUp();
    } else {
        box.removeClass("collapsed-box");
        bf.slideDown();
    }
});
```

i add `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Gallery Cover"` in selectbox but not show tooltip!

how do show tooltip top on select box ?!

DEMO [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypu5885r/)

Comment: Select2 hides the browsers select box, and shows DOM elements like `<a>` for the handler and `<ul>` for the list. You should somehow add the `data-toggle` attribute to the anchor which triggers the 'custom' selectbox, instead of adding it to the `<select>` element itself, which is not shown and as such cannot be used to trigger something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Replace :

`$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();`

With

`$(".selectD").tooltip();`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/ypu5885r/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code and worked for me.
removing title from select2 and adding it to tooltip function

```
$('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');
$('.select2-selection__rendered').tooltip({
    title:'title here',
    placement: "auto"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There was an issue with your bootstrap classes.

try this Fiddle: http: //jsfiddle.net/ypu5885r/1/

Comment: you remove selct2 design from select box!! o_O

Comment: you read my question?!!! i active select2 plugin with `.selectD` so if u remove this select2 not work !